# Windows permission - Deny sub-folder creation but allow files editing

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions

I'm currently trying to setup a folder on a file server (Windows Server 2012 r2) where some users can create and edit files, but not create sub-folders. I assumed it would be easy with advanced permissions, just unchecking  "Create/append folders" should do the trick, so I did just that.

However, when I do that, users with said permissions can only open files in the folder in read-only mode. Even more confusing, they can still do everything else like save under a different name, create a file, delete a file... so in a way, they can still edit a file (by saving it under name "file2", deleting "file1", then renaming "file2" to "file1"), but it's a huge pain.

I tried with Excel, Word and even .txt files so I can assume all types of files are affected.

I stumbled upon [this](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2126660-restrict-new-folder-creation) while googling my problem but adding a deny rule as suggested only gets me to the same result.

Is there something I'm missing?

Btw if this of any importance this happens both on Windows 10 clients and on a W2012R2 RDP.

Comment: Quick answer: you'll need to explicitly set different permissions for the files in the folder than for the folder itself, which you can do in the GUI using the "applies to" options.  If nobody else has posted a full answer I'll try to come back and do so later today.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I just tried it and it works, thanks a lot !
      
So just to be clear : under Security tab->Advanced, you need to set 2 sets of permissions for any concerned group :
One applied to folders, subfolders and files where you un-check  the "Create/append folders" permission.
And another one applied TO FILES ONLY where you give them regular edit permissions.

Still I have to say, this is incredibly counter-intuitive that unchecking the "Create/append folders" box affects others things than folders. Kinda defeat the whole purpose actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set it up like this:

[image: Advanced Security Settings example]

In case you find the picture hard to read, here are the entries in text form:

- Administrators: Full control, applies to this folder, subfolders and files
- Users: Full control, applies to files only
- Users: Create files / write data, applies to this folder only
- Users: Read & execute, applies to this folder, subfolders and files

(The variant described in your self-answer will work too, doing it this way just makes the intent slightly more clear to someone looking at it later.)

The underlying issue is that files and folders share the same set of permissions, and some of them have a different meaning for files than for folders.

In particular, the "create folders / append data" access right has these effects:

- For a folder, it allows you to create new subfolders in the folder.
- For a file, it allows you to append data at the end of the file.

So if an application doesn't have that right to a particular file, it can't make that file any longer than it already is.  For that matter, according to a strict reading of the documentation, it can't make it any smaller either - but I'm not sure that's actually true. :-)

At any rate, that will typically mean that the application can't open the file for writing at all.  Most applications ask for generic write access when opening files for editing, and that includes the append data right.  In this scenario that won't work and the application will typically either fail entirely or fall back to read-only mode.

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out the solution thanks to Harry Johnston's comment, cheers to him :

Under Security tab->Advanced, you need to set 2 sets of permissions for any concerned group :

-One applied to folders, subfolders and files (the default) where you un-check the "Create/append folders" permission.

-One applied **TO FILES ONLY** where you give them regular edit permissions.

Still I have to say, this is incredibly counter-intuitive that unchecking the "Create/append folders" box affects others things than folders. Kinda defeat the whole purpose actually.

Comment: On my system, it says "Create folders / append data" which, while still potentially confusing, is at least technically accurate.  Are you running Windows in a language other than English?  Perhaps there was a problem with the translation.

Answer (score 0):

I am on window 2019 standard edition. I followed Harry's instruction closely, tied multiple times with 2 different groups. Unfortunately not work. After the change, the result is opposite to the expectation: the user can create new folder, but not new files. I also followed Ola's solution, got the same result.
Anything I missed? I have exact screenshot as Harry...
Christine

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/543611)